# How do I detect if antd select search was not successful (in React)?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using a searchable select component from `antd` and I need to detect if the search was unsuccessful (I need to add a UI button in that case). But, I can't seem to find any props for it in `antd` docs.

I've tried this:

```
<Select dropdownAlign={{ offset: [-15, 4] }}
              showSearch
              placeholder="Select a medicine"
              suffixIcon={
                // <HiOutlineArrowDown color="#29BCC1" />
                <img src={arrowdropdown} alt />
              }
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, "select", "medicine")}
              onSelect={(e) => setMed(e)}
              filterOption={(input, option) => {
                  if(!(option?.children?.toLowerCase()?.startsWith(input?.toLowerCase()))) {
                    console.log("no result")
                  }
                
                return option?.children?.toLowerCase()?.startsWith(input?.toLowerCase())
              }}
              value={med}
              className="c_select"
            >
              {props.medicine.data?.map((med, index) => (
                <Option value={med.id} key={index}>
                  {med.name}
                </Option>
              ))}
            </Select>
```

This is working, but the problem is that `console.log("no result")` logs about a 1000 times which is very inefficient. So, please guide me if there's a much better way to solve this issue. Thanks.

P.S: I'm using `antd: 4.21.3` with `react: 18.2.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I added an `onSearch` prop to my Select component and passed in `handleMedicineSearch` function to it. The function is below:

```
function handleMedicineSearch(value) {
    const filteredOptions = props.medicine.data?.filter((item) => {
      return item?.name?.toLowerCase()?.startsWith(value?.toLowerCase());
    })

    if(filteredOptions.length === 0) {
      setShowAddBtn(true);
    }

    else {
      setShowAddBtn(false);
    }
  }
```

The line:

`if(filteredOptions.length === 0)`

is used to detect if the search was unsuccessful.